# Alarm for every 1000s number

Tags: python, blockchain

I'm getting a number through API request and want to have an Alarm (in the future get it on Telegram or Android / IOS notification - still don't know how to do that) for every whole 1000s step the number increases.

```
import ui
import requests

v = ui.load_view('Blockalarm')
v.present('sheet')

getblock = 'http://explorer.diverseproject.co/api/getblockcount'
json_data = requests.get(getblock).json()
currentblock = str(json_data)
crntblk = v['crntblk']
crntblk.text = currentblock
```

The number I get currently is 52400.
So the next number my alarm should go off would be 53000.

How would i get the alarm to know when the next step is being reached / to split the number?

Comment: Hi, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry. Language barrier ;)
Hope i can describe it better...

How would i get the alarm to know when the next step is being reached / to split the number?

Edited my text.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it is still not clear what the actual problem is. Are you asking how to set off an alarm, or how to round a number to the next whole 1000?

Comment: I would need to check if the number i get already reached 53000 and then if it reached 54000 and so on. 
I would check for it every 30min i guess.

Comment: So you run your script every 30 min, and if the number was 52400 in the previous run and now it is 53100 it should do something? In that case you will need a place (such as a file on disk) to persistently store the last number. Alternatively, use a loop and sleep inside.

Comment: My main problem is, how to check the new number for the "thousand point". So if it's 53k and next check 54k and so on, with a loop.

Comment: You can use something like `math.ceil(number / 1000) * 1000` to get the next higher multiple of 1000.

Comment: Thx @kazemakase :)
Got it all!